# How to make a variable from a vertical list

Tags: python, list, csv

I'm getting names from a csv file and putting them in a list, then I want to make those names output vertically through a variable.

Cant seem to get the list to come out how I want, I tried using a for loop and formatting a string with the variable.

```
def gd():
    house =  "gr"
    names_list = []

    with open('names.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)

        for line in csv_reader:
            names_list.append(line['gd'])

        for name in names_list:
            names = f'{name}\n'

    names_label.configure(text=names)
```

IM using tkinter module to make a gui, I want the names from the csv file to be outputted to a label on the gui vertically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need to add the plus equal operator:

```
names += f'{name}\n
```

And at the beginning:

```
names = ""
```

Answer (score 0):

An ideomatic way to do this is to use the `join` method of strings.

```
In [1]: import os

In [2]: names_list = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']

In [3]: os.linesep.join(names_list)
Out[3]: 'foo\nbar\nbaz'

In [4]: print(os.linesep.join(names_list))
foo
bar
baz
```

Keep in mind that `os.linesep` is the standard line separator for the platform you are using. On UNIX it is equivalent to `'\n'.join(...)`.

Note that you can use an arbitrary string.

```
In [7]: ' '.join(names_list)
Out[7]: 'foo bar baz'

In [8]: ', '.join(names_list)
Out[8]: 'foo, bar, baz'
```